# Is it possible to edit firebird database, alter trigger without connecting to it?

Tags: firebird

Is it possible to edit firebird database, alter trigger without connecting to it, using raw .fdb file or .gbak?

Comment: In theory, Firebird is Open Source. You can take its sources and remake them into the editor you want. In practice that is not possible without very heavy work to produce such tools. But why would you need it ?

Comment: for example i have physical access to server, on which firebird is installed, but there are sme restrictions, like the one mentioned here: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq344/ so i can not connect. How to edit this trigger in other way? (its not exactly based or ip addr but something similar)

Comment: Basically it seems you want to crack the security. For whatever reason, reasonable or not, that we can not see. Also that question is specifically addressed in Firebird manual.

Comment: You really should include all relevant information in your question, including the fact that you are trying to circumvent a database trigger. Sometimes there is a simpler solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although with sufficient knowledge of the internal structure of Firebird it would be possible to edit the file directly, in practice that is not a viable way (and would be a great way to corrupt your database).

Users with admin rights can disable firing database triggers on connect for a connection, see also [Database Triggers](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-trgr-dbtrigger).

For example when you use ISQL, you can start it with `isql -nodbtriggers`. This only works with SYSDBA, or if you have the `RDB$ADMIN` role and if you specify that role on connect.